# Kotlin: I in range

Tags: kotlin, intellij-idea

```
val x= readLine()!!.toInt()
for (i in 1..x) {
    repeat(x) { print("#") }
    println()
}
```

I am trying to create a program in which the user inputs a number and the output is that number in hashtags, eg, input 3, output # ## ###, however, right now, if i input 3, the output is ###,###,###

Answer (score 1, accepted):

inside repeat use **i** instead of x.

```
fun main() {
    val x= 3
    for (i in 1..x) {
        repeat(i) { print("#") }
        println()
    }
}
```